# adding data to nested document : mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, object, nosql, aggregation-framework

I want to add new record within 'music'. My document looks similar to

```
{
  "username": "erkin",
  "email": "erkin-07@hotmail.com",
  "password": "b",
  "playlists": [
    {
      "_id": 58,
      "name": "asdsa",
      "date": "09-01-15",
      "musics": {
        "song-one":{
          "song-one": "INNA - Cola Song (feat. J Balvin)",
          "duration": "3.00"
        },
        "song-two":{
          "song-two": "blabla",
          "duration": "3.00"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After navigating to "music" and then using $set to add/update multiple records at once. But new records is getting added in lexicographical manner(behaviour of $set).

I'm using query similar to (so in my case song-four is coming before song-three) :

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').update({username:"erkin"},{$set:{"playlists.musics.song-three":{...},"playlists.musics.song-four":{...}}})
```

Is there any way I can add new records to that location in a way my $set query is arranged ?

Answer (score 1):

As `playlists` is an array:

**Option 1: Update the first document in `playlists`.**

Specify the index: 0 for the first document in `playlists`.

```
playlists.0.musics.song-three
```

```
db.collection.update({
  username: "erkin"
},
{
  $set: {
    "playlists.0.musics.song-three": {
      "song-three": "song-three"
    },
    "playlists.0.musics.song-four": {
      "song-four": "song-four"
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Demo on Mongo Playground (Option 1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZFRv0Jot_af)

---

**Option 2: Update all documents in `playlists`.**

With [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#mongodb-update-up.---) all positional operator.

```
playlists.$[].musics.song-three
```

```
db.collection.update({
  username: "erkin"
},
{
  $set: {
    "playlists.$[].musics.song-three": {
      "song-three": "song-three"
    },
    "playlists.$[].musics.song-four": {
      "song-four": "song-four"
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Demo on Mongo Playground (Option 2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nB9pFLj1g_c)

---

**Option 3: Update specified document in `playlists`.**

With [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) filtered positional operator.

```
playlists.$[playlist].musics.song-three
```

```
db.collection.update({
  username: "erkin"
},
{
  $set: {
    "playlists.$[playlist].musics.song-three": {
      "song-three": "song-three"
    },
    "playlists.$[playlist].musics.song-four": {
      "song-four": "song-four"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "playlist._id": 58
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Demo on Mongo Playground (Option 3)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dEzXwf87wmh)